# The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Students>()' could not be translated

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I am getting below error while executing LINQ query -

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet()' could not be translated.
> Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch
> to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable',
> 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

The issue is occurring in one of the join

```
var result = await (from stds in _context.Student
                    join depts in _context.departments on stds.DeptId equals depts.id into a
                    from b in a.Where(f => f.stdId == 123 && f.Premium.Value).DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new StudentModel 
                    { 
                       stdName = b.stdName
                    }).ToListAsync();
```

I tried using ToList() and other options instead of ToListAsync() but nothing is working. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: are you able to get students without joining? All students?

Comment: Yes query runs fine if I remove join @JosephWambura

Comment: Don't use join, use a navigation property like `Student.Department`.

Comment: Can you please provide the student and department classes?

Comment: .NET Core 3.1 reaches End-Of-Life **today**. That means it won't even get security patches, and NuGet authors will start to drop support for it. The current Long Term Support version is .NET 6.0, supported until 2024

Comment: If the entities had proper navigation properties the query could be as simple as `ctx.Students.Where(std=>std.Department.stdId==123 && std.Department.Premium).Select(std=>std.Name)`

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT JOIN` can be expressed also by `SelectMany`. `GroupJoin` has very limited translation support.

```cs
var query = 
    from stds in _context.Student
    from depts in _context.departments
        .Where(depts => stds.DeptId == depts.id)
        .Where(depts => depts.stdId == 123 && depts.Premium.Value)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new StudentModel 
    { 
        stdName = depts.stdName
    };
```